# Configure Python interpreter for notebook in vscode to be the same as the interpreter for a conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

From my understanding of this [source](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/) and what a python interpreter is, if I have an environment like this:

```
$ conda activate myenv
(myenv) $ python3
> import pandas as pd
>
```

With no errors. And `which python3` returns
`/AbsPath/.conda/envs/myenv/bin/python3`

Then in my Notebook in vscode I should be able to select this interpreter in the command pallet and not have an error importing pandas.

So open `my-notebook.ipynb`. Open command pallet and select `Python: Select Interpreter`, click `+ Enter interpreter path` and then paste `/AbsPath/.conda/envs/myenv/bin/python3` then I should be able to execute a cell that contains

(The [vscode website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_setting-up-your-environment) says I should be able to set the interpreter for Jupyter Notebook environments this way.)

```
import pandas as pd
```

And not have an error thrown. But I get the error that I have no module named Pandas.

Am I doing something incorrectly or is this unexpected weird behavior?

I don't think it's actually using the correct interpreter because

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Prints `/bin/python3` from my notebook while this same command from the command line gives me `/AbsPath/.conda/envs/myenv/bin/python3`.

I tried

```
import sys
sys.executable = '/AbsPath/.conda/envs/myenv/bin/python3'
```

To override it but that didn't work (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether you have **chosen the correct kernel**.

Click the button in the upper right corner of the `.ipynb` file.

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook) and [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_setting-up-your-environment) for more details if you are new to jupyter notebook.

[image]

Comment: that solved it, thanks. Might want to update the docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_setting-up-your-environment) but makes sense